# What can prevent a working (when "opened with" Python) Python application from starting by double-click?

Tags: python

A Python application (having a permission to be executed by the user) doesn't start with double click on it. If I run it (directly, by `./theapp.pyw`) in terminal I get ": No such file or directory" error (while there is no such a string in the application code and the file surely exists (renaming it and using a different name results in the same)).

But If I explicitly open it with Python (by issuing `python ./theapp.pyw` or right-clicking and choosing to open with Python 2.7) it works just fine.

The first line of the file says

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Issuing "/usr/bin/env python" command launches Python 2.7 console.

The OS is XUbuntu Linux 11.10. The only Python installed is Ubuntu's default 2.7.

Any ideas?

Comment: Dumb question perhaps, but what are the permissions?

Comment: See the first sentence, @nate, in the parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pyw files are for windows
http://filext.com/file-extension/PYW

And in windows the shebang line is ignored.
Just work with the .py script.

You can also try creating a bash script that launches your python scripts with the specific flags that you want.

Comment: `dos2unix ./theapp.pyw` solved the problem which seemed to be indeed in CR+LF line endings. I've mistakenly thought that .pyw extension was just meaning a GUI application (as opposed to a console script).